# Clang++: weird error message

Tags: c++, clang++

I try to compile a simple class, but I always get the same error:

```
≥ clang++ LIF_network.cpp -std=c++11                                                                         
LIF_network.cpp:3:1: error: expected unqualified-id
public LIF_network::LIF_network(){
^
1 error generated.
```

.hpp:

```
#ifndef LIF_NETWORK_HPP
#define LIF_NETWORK_HPP
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "LIF_neuron.hpp"
#include "currentTimer.hpp"

#define MAX_TIME 15

class LIF_network{
    public:
        LIF_network();
};

#endif //LIF_NETWORK_HPP
```

.cpp:

```
#include "LIF_network.hpp"

public LIF_network::LIF_network(){
    mNumNeurons = 0;
    mNeurons = std::vector<std::vector<LIF_neuron>>();
    mOutput = std::vector<double>();
    mCurrentTimer = CurrentTimer(MAX_TIME, mNumNeurons);
}
```

The error message does not really help me. Can you spot my mistake? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The compiler spotted the mistake for you already. `public` has no place in the constructor definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The access specifier (public: private: and protected:) only works within a class definition and not outside of it.  It looks like you are trying to port Java code.

Comment: I worked too long with java. What an obvious mistake... Sorry for taking your time, but thanks a lot for the help.